# My raycaster doesn't work right when it gets further from the point (0,0)

Tags: c++, raycasting

When I make a 16x16 tile where the size of every map is 64 bits everything worked fine. However, when I make a 60x60 map, the rays can no longer detects few walls anymore.

[image: Here is how it is supposed to work]

As you can see, the rays at when casted by the player when the player is at(2013.69,2043.34) works normally. The blue line behind blue walls is the 2D rays.

[image: Here is the problem]

However, when moving the player just a few steps further to (2124.59,2215.76) the rays don't work properly, clipping through wall.

I guessed the problem derived from calculation with big numbers. I want to know why is this happening.
I have tried fixing this by making the player player stand still while scrolling the map but coudn't do it smoothly.

**Here is my code:**

```
    void castRay(Map* &mp)
    {
        int map_x, map_y, map_point, dof;//depth of field which is how many lines need to be checked
        float ray_x, ray_y, ray_angle, ray_offset_x, ray_offset_y;
        float v_distance = 1e9, h_distance = 1e9, wall_distance;
        float vx, vy, hx, hy;

        int tile_size = mp->tileSize;
        ray_angle = player_angle-30*D;
        if(ray_angle > 2*PI)
                ray_angle -= 2*PI;
        else if(ray_angle < 0)
                ray_angle += 2*PI;

        for(int r = 0; r < 60; r++)
        {
            //Checking horizontal line
            float aTan = -1/tan(ray_angle);
            dof = 0;
            if(ray_angle > PI)
            {
                ray_y = (((int)center_y/mp->tileSize)*mp->tileSize)-0.0001;
                ray_x = center_x + (center_y-ray_y)*aTan;
                ray_offset_y = -mp->tileSize;
                ray_offset_x = -ray_offset_y*aTan;
            }
            else if(ray_angle < PI)
            {
                ray_y = (((int)center_y/mp->tileSize)*mp->tileSize)+mp->tileSize;
                ray_x = center_x + (center_y-ray_y)*aTan;
                ray_offset_y = mp->tileSize;
                ray_offset_x = -ray_offset_y*aTan;
            }
            else if(ray_angle == 0 || ray_angle == PI)
            {
                ray_x = center_x;
                ray_y = center_y;
                dof = max(mp->Map_Width,mp->Map_Height);
            }

            while(dof < max(mp->Map_Width,mp->Map_Height))
            {
                map_x = (int)ray_x/mp->tileSize;
                map_y = (int)ray_y/mp->tileSize;
                map_point = map_y*mp->Map_Width+map_x;
                hx = ray_x;
                hy = ray_y;
                h_distance = sqrt((ray_x-center_x)*(ray_x-center_x)+(ray_y-center_y)*(ray_y-center_y));
                if(map_point > 0 && map_point < mp->Map_Size && mp->Map_Tilemap[map_point] == 2)
                {

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ray_x += ray_offset_x;
                    ray_y += ray_offset_y;
                    dof++;
                }
            }

            //vertical ray
            dof = 0;
            float nTan = -tan(ray_angle);
            if(ray_angle > PI/2 && ray_angle < 3*PI/2)
            {
                ray_x = (((int)center_x/mp->tileSize)*mp->tileSize)-0.0001;
                ray_y = center_y + (center_x-ray_x)*nTan;
                ray_offset_x = -mp->tileSize;
                ray_offset_y = -ray_offset_x*nTan;
            }
            else if(ray_angle < PI/2 || ray_angle > 3*PI/2)
            {
                ray_x = (((int)center_x/mp->tileSize)*mp->tileSize)+mp->tileSize;
                ray_y = center_y + (center_x-ray_x)*nTan;
                ray_offset_x = mp->tileSize;
                ray_offset_y = -ray_offset_x*nTan;
            }
            else if(ray_angle == 0 || ray_angle == PI)
            {
                ray_x = center_x;
                ray_y = center_y;
                dof = max(mp->Map_Width,mp->Map_Height);
            }

            while(dof < max(mp->Map_Width,mp->Map_Height))
            {
                map_x = (int)ray_x/mp->tileSize;
                map_y = (int)ray_y/mp->tileSize;
                map_point = map_y*mp->Map_Width+map_x;
                vx = ray_x;
                vy = ray_y;
                v_distance = sqrt((ray_x-center_x)*(ray_x-center_x)+(ray_y-center_y)*(ray_y-center_y));
                if(map_point > 0 && map_point < mp->Map_Size && mp->Map_Tilemap[map_point] == 2)
                {

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ray_x += ray_offset_x;
                    ray_y += ray_offset_y;
                    dof++;
                }
            }
            ray_angle += D;
            if(ray_angle > 2*PI)
                ray_angle -= 2*PI;
            else if(ray_angle < 0)
                ray_angle += 2*PI;

            float wall_distance;
            if(v_distance < h_distance)
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game::renderer,0,0,255,255);
                wall_distance = v_distance;
                ray_x = vx;
                ray_y = vy;
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(game::renderer,0,0,230,255);
                wall_distance = h_distance;
                ray_x = hx;
                ray_y = hy;
            }

            SDL_RenderDrawLineF(game::renderer,center_x,center_y,ray_x,ray_y);

            //3D Magic
            float cam_angle = player_angle-ray_angle;
            if(cam_angle < 0)
            {
                cam_angle += 2*PI;
            }
            if(cam_angle > 2*PI)
            {
                cam_angle -= 2*PI;
            }
            wall_distance *= cos(cam_angle);
            float wall_height = (600*320)/wall_distance;
            if(wall_height > 320)
                wall_height = 320;

            float wall_offset = 200-wall_height/2;
            for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            {
                SDL_RenderDrawLineF(game::renderer,r*8+512+k,wall_offset,r*8+512+k,wall_offset+wall_height);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `ray_angle == PI` -- Comparing floating point values for equality is not recommended, due to floating point values rarely ever will be totally equal to each other in real applications.

Comment: Also `-1/tan(ray_angle)` is numerically unstable (when tan(ray_angle) approaches 0) and can introduce large errors. Try to avoid using 1/tan  and find some other way to calculate what you need.

Comment: A follow-up to @PepijnKramer's suggestion - do not use angles, use vector components instead, this will remove the potential division by zero problem.